# Alternate solution to indefinite integral

Tags: integration

$\int{\frac{x}{(-10+7x-x^2)^{3/2}}}dx$

Is there any alternative way to solve this indefinite integral?(Other than trig substituition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$I(x)=\int \frac{xdx}{(7x-10-x^2)^{3/2}}=\frac{ax+b}{(7x-10-x^2)^{1/2}}$$
D.w.r.t. $x$ gives
$$\frac{x}{(7x-10-x^2)^{3/2}}=\frac{(-20a-7b)/2+(7a/2+b)x}{(7x-10-x^2)^{3/2}}$$
So we get $a=14/9, b=-40/9$.

Comment: sir the integral should be $\int{\frac{x}{(-10+7x-x^2)^{3/2}}}dx$ I think you have ,missed an x in the numerator or am I missing something?

Comment: OK, now I have corrected it accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, no logarithmic term answer is given by putting $a,b$ in the first equation here

Comment: How do you know that the numerator is $ax+b$ ?

Comment: If you take a quadratic $ax+b+cx^2$ up then $c$ will turn out to be 0.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing the shape of the denominator, we can investigate the following two derivatives:

$$\left(\dfrac1{\sqrt{-10+7x-x^2}}\right)'=-\frac12\frac{7-2x}{(-10+7x-x^2)^{3/2}}$$

and

$$\left(\dfrac x{\sqrt{-10+7x-x^2}}\right)'=\frac{-10+7x-x^2}{(-10+7x-x^2)^{3/2}}-\frac12\frac{x(7-2x)}{(-10+7x-x^2)^{3/2}}
\\=\frac{-10+\dfrac72x}{(-10+7x-x^2)^{3/2}}.$$

Now you can form a linear combination to obtain the numerator $x$.